# How do I switch between users, without logging out?

Tags: lightdm, users, display-manager, xscreensaver

I am using Lubuntu, my desktop environment is lxQt and screensaver is xScreensaver.

I'm trying to figure out a way to switch between users, (e.g. when pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>).

Even though, it is possible to lock the screen with xscreensaver, I'm unable to use "new login" button and it shows this message:

> could not excute "gdmflexiserver": No such file or directory

**Update 1**

I have come up with something I judge to be a hacky solution: creating a keyboard shortcut that triggers `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`.

Although, as I said: it's more like a hack than a solution. It also makes me authenticate twice: once for LightDM and another for XScreenSaver, which is not very convenient.

Comment: I think you have the rite tool `dm-tool` go through its manpage http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dm-tool.1.html

Comment: switch-to-user USERNAME [SESSION]
              Switch  to  a  user  session.   If  this user is already logged in then the display
              manager will switch to that session,  otherwise  a  new  session  is  started.   If
              authentication  is  required  a greeter will start to collect this.  If the session
              option is provided then this session type will be used, otherwise the  default  for
              this user is used.

Comment: Do you want a whole desktop environment with the second user, or is it enough to run a window or two with the second user (within the desktop environment of the first user)?